Question on the root
Is it true that the smallest root $t$ of the polynomial
$$
20 t^3 - 30 t^2 + (12 - 4 \cos^2 \alpha - 4 \cos^2 \beta - 4 \cos^2 \gamma) t + \cos^2 \alpha + \cos^2 \beta + \cos^2 \gamma - 2 \cos \alpha \cos \beta \cos \gamma - 1
$$
is always no greater than $\frac{1}{5}$ for all $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in [0,\pi]$ with $\alpha + \beta \geq \gamma$, $\alpha + \gamma \geq \beta$, $\beta + \gamma \geq \alpha$, and $\alpha + \beta + \gamma \leq 2\pi$?
Thanks a lot for any helpful answer.
I have also posted the same question to MathOverflow.

Is this a question for https://math.stackexchange.com?

@MelaGo  To find the answer this question, wouldn't computations be needed? Thanks.

Can any one use Lagrangian Multiplier method in Mathematics to find the bound for the smallest $t$? Thanks.

@vivian Please provide your Mathematica code, this will increase your chance to get helpful answers!

@vivian Did you modify your question? Fromer version of  "not greater than 1/5" was 2/5 I think

@UlrichNeumann Because the condition was revised. Thanks.

@vivian It would be good style to give a hint of such modifications! By the way the numerical result of my answer shows that this assumption isn't fullfilled!

@UlrichNeumann  Could you find the EXACT maximum? Thanks a lot.

I don’t see much of a Mathematica question here. No code attempt provided, for one thing.

@vivian Is the underlying problem of a geometric nature? Please give some details!

@vivian Again you modified your question( now additional constraints) without notification, no good style.

Do not change the original question. If you have another question then start a new thread.

@vivian, for your further questions, please include the information that you have cross-posted the same question to another site.

Using @UlrichNeumann answer. Replacing Sqrt[# Conjugate[#] with Re[#] finds a real root that can be expressed as root approximant. So there must exist a rigorous proof that $\frac{1}{10} \left(5-\sqrt{15}\right)$ is the upper bound.
By the way if the found root were complex then the result would be inconclusive, but we were lucky that the root was real.
gl = 20 t^3 \[Minus] 
   30 t^2 + (12 \[Minus] 4 Cos[\[Alpha]]^2 \[Minus] 
      4 Cos[\[Beta]]^2 \[Minus] 4 Cos[\[Gamma]]^2) t + 
   Cos[\[Alpha]]^2 + Cos[\[Beta]]^2 + Cos[\[Gamma]]^2 \[Minus] 
   2 Cos[\[Alpha]] Cos[\[Beta]] Cos[\[Gamma]] \[Minus] 1;
solt = Solve[gl == 0, t];
NMaximize[{Min@Map[Re[#] &, t /. solt // ToRadicals], 
   0 <= \[Alpha] <= Pi, 0 <= \[Beta] <= Pi, 
   0 <= \[Gamma] <= Pi, \[Alpha] + \[Beta] + \[Gamma] < 
    2 Pi}, {\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma]}, WorkingPrecision -> 100];
Min[t /. Solve[gl == 0 /. %[[2]]]] // RootApproximant


$$\frac{1}{10} \left(5-\sqrt{15}\right)$$

Hello, how reliable is RootApproximant of Mathematica for EXACT maximum? Thanks.

It is very reliable. You can check it with increasing WorkingPrecision and comparing with output of RootApproximant.

Is there any effective way in Mathematica to show that it is the EXACT maximum? Thanks.

You can try Maximize instead of NMaximize which outputs exact solutions but it does not work in all circumstances.

Why does Lagrangian Multiplier method in Mathematica does not work for the question either? Is there any other way to show that it is the EXACT maximum? Thanks.

@vivian: You asked "how reliable is RootApproximant of Mathematica for EXACT maximum?". The command Solve[20*t^3 -      30 t^2 + (12 - 4 Cos[a]^2 - 4 Cos[b]^2 - 4 Cos[c]^2)*t +      Cos[a]^2 + Cos[b]^2 + Cos[c]^2 - 2 (Cos[a]*Cos[b]*Cos[c]) - 1 ==     0 /. {a -> Pi/2, b -> Pi/2, c -> Pi/2}, t] outputs {{t -> 1/2}, {t -> 1/10 (5 - Sqrt[15])}, {t -> 1/10 (5 + Sqrt[15])}}.

modified (Thanks @azerbajdzan's helpful comment)
J[\[Alpha]_?NumericQ, \[Beta]_?NumericQ, \[Gamma]_?NumericQ] := 
 Block[{solN}, 
  solN = NSolve[-1 - 30 t^2 + 20 t^3 + Cos[\[Alpha]]^2 + 
      Cos[\[Beta]]^2 - 2 Cos[\[Alpha]] Cos[\[Beta]] Cos[\[Gamma]] + 
      Cos[\[Gamma]]^2 + 
      t (12 - 4 Cos[\[Alpha]]^2 - 4 Cos[\[Beta]]^2 - 
         4 Cos[\[Gamma]]^2) == 0, t, Reals  ] ;
  Min[t /. solN] ]

maxi = NMaximize[{ J[ \[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma]] , 
   0 <= \[Alpha] <= Pi, 0 <= \[Beta] <= Pi, 
   0 <= \[Gamma] <= Pi, \[Alpha] + \[Beta] + \[Gamma] < 
    2 Pi}, { \[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma]}, 
  Method -> {"NelderMead", 
    "InitialPoints" -> {{Pi, 0, 0}, {0, Pi, 0}, {0, 0, Pi}, {Pi/2, 
       Pi/2, Pi/2}}}]
(*{0.112702, {\[Alpha] -> 1.5708, \[Beta] -> 1.5708, \[Gamma] ->1.5708}}*)


NSolve[gl /. maxi[[2]], t, Reals] (*{0.112702, {\[Alpha] -> 1.5708,\[Beta] -> 1.5708, \[Gamma] ->1.5708}}*)

The upper bond of the smallest t 0.112702 is smaller than  1/5!

Thank you for your answer. But could you please find the EXACT maximum? Thanks a lot.

Would you be able to complete running your code by removing the 'N'? Thanks.

@vivian Unfortunately Maximize (Mathematica v 12.2) doesn't evaluate a symbolic result

This does not seem to be right to me. You are maximizing absolute value of roots but OP does not say anything about absolute value. Roots can be negative. And indeed the root is -0.330541 not +0.330541.

@UlrichNeumann  Then is there any effective way to find the EXACT maximum? Thanks.

@azerbajdzan Thanks for your hint, I'll modify my answer!

A straightforward approach succeeds:
f[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := 
 Minimize[{t, 20*t^3 - 30 t^2 + (12 - 4 Cos[a]^2 - 4 Cos[b]^2 - 4 Cos[c]^2)*t + 
  Cos[a]^2 + Cos[b]^2 + Cos[c]^2 - 2 (Cos[a]*Cos[b]*Cos[c]) - 1 ==
  0}, t] // First
NMaximize[{f[a, b, c],  a >= 0 && a <= Pi && b >= 0 && b <= Pi && c >= 0 && 
c <= Pi &&   a + b >= c && b + c >= a && a + c >= b && a + b + c <= 2*Pi}, {a,  b, c}]


{0.112701, {a -> 1.5708, b -> 1.5708, c -> 1.5708}}


In the above Minimize can be replaced by NMinimize in 14.1 on Windows.
